# How can I use a ray cast to detect when something isn't there?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games, raycasting

So I'm using unity to attempt to recreate the game space invaders. In the game, there are several layers of aliens, and only the one on the bottom is supposed to shoot so that the aliens aren't shooting themselves. I am trying to use a ray cast to detect whether or not there's anything there, but either it does it regardless of anything in the way, or it doesn't shoot no matter what. I've tried a lot of things, but here's my most recent code. Thanks!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AlienShooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    float raycastLength = .6f;
    int randShoot;
    [SerializeField]
    int maxNumForBulletTime = 250;
    public Transform alienFirePoint;
    public GameObject alienBullet;

    void Start()
    {
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        RaycastHit2D rayCastHit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.down, .6f);

        if (rayCastHit.collider == null)
        {
        }
        else
            canShoot();
    }

    void canShoot()
    {
        randShoot = Random.Range(1, maxNumForBulletTime);
        if (randShoot == 5)
        {
            Instantiate(alienBullet, alienFirePoint.position, alienFirePoint.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the ray of alien collides or triggers another alien collider than deactivate shooting for that alien

Comment: Note that UnityScript is a deprecated Javascript derivative created for Unity. Your code is C#, a completely separate programming language.